# How do I generate a JSON Schema using oneOf

Tags: json, jsonschema

I have been objects in my system, and I automatically generate schema for them using code that looks like this:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
SchemaFactoryWrapper visitor = new SchemaFactoryWrapper();
try
{
  for (Class<?> annotatedClass : annotatedClasses)
  {
    mapper.acceptJsonFormatVisitor(annotatedClass, visitor);
    JsonSchema jsonSchema = visitor.finalSchema();
    String schemaString = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter()
        .writeValueAsString(jsonSchema);
```

I want to restrict the possible values of one of the fields in one of the annotatedClasses to a set of String values (for example one of say {"ONE", "TWO", "THREE"} or something similar.  Is there an annotation I can put on the field that will cause the oneOf restriction to be automatically generated in my schema?

Comment: You probably don't need `oneOf`, but perhaps `enum`?

Comment: Yes the answer is actually to use enum